# Is it possible to get a c file back?

Tags: c

i coded a project at C.
However I deleted my main.c file. But I have my .exe file. Is it possible to recompile the .exe file to a .c file? Or is the .c file lost forever?

thx for help

Comment: Maybe with deleted file recovery software, but not from the exe.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to get the C code back. Decompilers exist, but are not nearly good enough to produce sensible C code out of an .EXE file.

Lesson of the day: always use version control from the start. Commit often. Use remote server (like Github/Gitlab/etc, kot endorsing sny specific one) and pushing often, even incomplete code, is also wise.

Comment: Like @hyde said, you can decompile the executable, Ghidra (see https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra) comes with a built in decompiler - it is not perfect, but the code produced is readable.  You could start with the and manually edit it back to readable C code.  But always use some sort of backup!

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote the code recently, just rewrite it from scratch. You may have deleted the code from your hard drive, but not the underlying logic from your brain. And for sure you will avoid the errors you made before. So it will take less time than it took before.

If it is older code, you should dig in your backups. If you don't have any, you generally ask for trouble..........

Answer (score 0):

Your original source is gone forever<sup>1</sup>.

You can use a decompiler to generate a *new* .c file from the executable that's functionally equivalent<sup>2</sup>, but it won't be your original source code, and may not be very readable.

Variable names are not preserved in the machine code, nor are comments.  The structure may be slightly different from what you wrote depending on how aggressively the compiler optimized your code.

---

1. Unless you want to spend money on a file recovery service, but it's not worth it for one source file.

   I have never done this, so I can't give any specific recommendations or examples.